# R repetitive subset of lists nested within multiple lists

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data set that was supplied to me in .xlsx form with multiple workbooks with multiple sheets with the same names and similar columns of data within those sheets. I want to eventually join the data sheets with the same names and run some analysis.

As there is a lot of data in workbooks from multiple years I want to efficiently join the data and format, analysis etc... I am new to lists but have successfully read the data in but am having trouble sub setting and binding. I have made the following dummy data and script:

```
#tlm2009
b1<-c('a', 'b', 'c')
b2<-    c(4,    2,  3)
hab<-data.frame(b1,b2)

c1<-c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
c2<-    c(1,    2,  3, 4)
raw<-data.frame(c1,c2)

tlm2009<-list(hab,raw)

#tlm2010

b1<-c('a', 'b', 'c','d')
b2<-    c(1,    2,  3, 4)
hab<-data.frame(b1,b2)

c1<-c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', "e")
c2<-    c(1,    2,  3, 4, 5)
raw<-data.frame(c1,c2)

tlm2010<-list(hab,raw)

my.list<-list(tlm2009,tlm2010)
```

I have then run the following code to extract 'hab' and or 'raw' but it is not working

```
library(tidyverse)
unlist(my.list) %>%
    data.frame(val = .) %>%
    filter(str_detect(id, "(hab|raw)"))
```

and

```
library(purrr)
map(transpose(my.list),~map_dfc(.x,"hab"))
```

and get the following error for the transpose:

> Error in transpose(my.list) : Item 1 of list input is not an atomic vector

So I would like all the 'habs' subset and joined, I haven't really contemplated the joining yet as haven't got over the subset. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a note. If you run `library(tidyverse)`, there is no need to run `library(purrr)`. Also you didn't give names to your list hence can't use them?! Try using this: `tlm2010<-list(hab=hab,raw=raw)`?

Comment: What is your expected output? Perhaps there's an alternative way to  achieve the same? Could you copy and paste it to the question if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this

```
Map(rbind, my.list[[1]], my.list[[2]])

#[[1]]
#  b1 b2
#1  a  4
#2  b  2
#3  c  3
#4  a  1
#5  b  2
#6  c  3
#7  d  4

#[[2]]
#  c1 c2
#1  a  1
#2  b  2
#3  c  3
#4  d  4
#5  a  1
#6  b  2
#7  c  3
#8  d  4
#9  e  5
```

This automatically brings your `hab` and `raw` datasets together in one list by `rbind`ing them.

Comment: this looks like exactly what I want but when I run it the data looks strange. for example:

Comment: sorry. b1
   <fctr>
                      b2
                   <dbl>
ÿþaÿþ ÿþ4ÿþ  
ÿþbÿþ ÿþ2ÿþ  
ÿþcÿþ ÿþ3ÿþ

Comment: yeah the strings or numeric values are surrounded by ÿþ e.g. 'a' looks like ÿþaÿþ thanks

Comment: @Tom great, so did that work? Were you able to get your expected output?

Comment: it does except for when i run your code the output is surrounded e.g. the strings or numeric values are surrounded by ÿþ e.g. 'a' looks like ÿþaÿþ. I am using markdown for coding in r studio

Comment: @Tom might be an encoding or locale issue ?

Comment: I think I have sorted that problem @Ronak. Would I have to modify your code if I had different numbers of observations in some of the columns or some blank observations?

Comment: This should work as it is for blank as well as different number of rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192895/discussion-between-tom-and-ronak-shah).

Answer (score 0):

A general option would be to use `do.call` with `Map`. It can be also take `list`s of multiple lengths

```
do.call(Map, c(f = rbind, my.list))
#[[1]]
#  b1 b2
#1  a  4
#2  b  2
#3  c  3
#4  a  1
#5  b  2
#6  c  3
#7  d  4

#[[2]]
#  c1 c2
#1  a  1
#2  b  2
#3  c  3
#4  d  4
#5  a  1
#6  b  2
#7  c  3
#8  d  4
#9  e  5
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
pmap(my.list, bind_rows)
```